# Looping bug with a condition inside

Tags: python

I am trying to loop a list and store de max value on a variable, but when I debugging I found a bug which don't store the maximum well.

```
walls = [0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 0, 2]

def snow_stored_cuadratic(walls):
    max_height = 0

    for wall in walls:
        value = walls[wall]
        if value > max_height:
            max_height = value
    return max_height
```

When I go to the 4th value, which is 2 and I have store on my variable value the value of 1, the If statement to compare value > max_height gets stuck with the number 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note, that `wall` is not an index, it is an element of your list.

instead of `value` and this expression:

```
value = walls[wall]
```

just use `wall`

Moreover, use of the loop is not necessary, you can use `max()` function.

```
max_height = max(walls)
```

Answer (score 2):

You don'tt need to do `value = walls[wall]`, `wall` represents an element in the list and it is not an index.

```py
for wall in walls:
    if wall > max_height:
        max_height = wall
return max_height
```

Answer (score 0):

```
walls = [0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 0, 2]

def snow_stored_cuadratic(walls):
    max_height = 0

    for wall in walls:
        if wall > max_height:
            max_height = value
    return max_height
```

You dont need to write the index, as you loop for each elements. `wall` will be 0,1,0,....,0,2 in each iteration, so no need to write it as an index

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in function max().

```py
print(max(walls))
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to get a max value from the list.
Instead of using your function try use just that which will return your max value from `walls` list

```
walls = [0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 0, 2]
print (max(walls))
```

this will print:

```
5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for wall in walls:
```

The wall in above line takes element of the list when iterate.
So if you want it to behave as index value of the list you should use it as

```
for wall, ele in enumerate(walls):
```

By using enumerate you can get index value in wall and each element in ele. And using your code with enumerate it works fine.